# Hanoi tower recursion with a move function that moves indexed rings

Tags: algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I've got a problem with a Hanoi tower recursion problem. I'm given a move function that takes 2 arguments :

- `j` (the index of a ring : `1` -> `n` from bottom to top) and
- a position.

I've found a way to the recursive problem without using this function but I'm stuck when I need to use it. In fact, I don't know how to change my `j` variable efficiently.

```
moveTower(n, position1, position2):
    if n > 1:
        moveTower(n-1, position1, aux)
        move(j, position2) """ That's where i'm stuck """
        moveTower(n-1, aux, position2)
    else:
        move(j, position2)
```

I've found some pattern for the evolution of `j`:

For example with 3 rings :

```
j = 3
j = 2
j = 3
j = 1
j = 3
j = 2
j = 3
```

Comment: Specifically, this problem has long been solved in a variety of explanation and implementation styles.  If you search on the phrase "Tower of Hanoi solution", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the simplest way to calculate `j` is to notice that it is always different from `position1` and `position2`. So you can write a nested`if/else`, or you can  pass it explicitly as the third parameter, or if you want a bit of clever magic, use:

```
j = 6 - position1 - position2
```

The idea here is that `6 = 1 + 2 + 3`, so this calculates `j` as the one of `(1,2,3)` that is not  `position1` or `position2`.

Comment: The spare spindle calculation was already pointed out via comments in a post which OP has since deleted (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54391194/2166798).  I think s/he hasn't yet realized that `j` really should be `n`, and all that's needed is a print statement describing the disc movement: "move the nth disc to position2."